# Distributing 'clean' Django project source code

Tags: django, software-distribution, web-development-server

I'm currently working on a small project in Django, which I would later like to publish on github, send to someone in a zip archive etc. While testing my app, I make changes to the server to see how it behaves. Now, if I want to publish my source code, I don't want it to contain any garbage I might have generated during the development process. Basically, whoever receives the code should have a minimal, clean version of it, and at the same time should be able to work with it out of the box. What is the best way to do this? Should I make migrations before publishing my code? Are there any standard practices?

Comment: i would suggest release the app with one migration file, that way you are responsible for it, and you know it works, and dont produces a lot of crap around it (like multiple migration files)...

Comment: For out of the box experience many developers use Docker.